# Using Prolog to process a list

Tags: list, prolog

I have a problem in Prolog.

Consider a list where each element is referring to a position/location in the same list.

I want to write a program which returns true if I start with the same location that I end in. For example:

If I give it `find-s([3,2,0,1],0)`

- It starts with 0 index which contains 3
- then goes to the 3 index which contains 1
- then the 1 index to find 2
- finally to index 2 which contains 0 !

so it returns true in this case

I tried this but it didn't work

```
position([Head1| Tail1], Var1) :-
 (   Head1 == Var1,
    Tail1 == Var1 ->
     true

 ).
```

Comment: Looks like you need to study your fundamental Prolog a little further. Prolog predicates don't return anything like functions do. They succed or fail. And in the form `[Head1 | Tail1]` (a list), `Tail1` is the *rest* of the list, so it is, itself, a list. The check of `Tail1 == Var1` doesn't make sense. Also, does it need to exhaust all the elements in the list? For example, should `find-s([3,2,1,0], 0)` succeed? In your solution, you'd need to detect a loop. For instance, what do you expect to happen with, `find-s([1, 1, 3, 0], 0).`?

Comment: in your example it will go to index 0 which contain 1 , then to index 1 which contain 1 , it will not reach the start value 0 so it returns false :)

Comment: i knew that my solution is wrong , but i need the true solution for this problem

Comment: What about my other example, `find-s([3,2,1,0], 0)`?

Comment: I realize you "need the true solution for this problem," but your attempt is scant and indicates very little understanding of basic Prolog. It also makes no logical sense. So rather than solve the whole problem for you, including explaining the basics of Prolog, I'll recommend studying, for example, [P-99: Ninety-Nine Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/) to gain some understanding of how list processing works. That will enable you to make a more informed attempt at solving the problem and make for a better question.

Comment: In Prolog, it helps to try to *read* your predicate. In this case, your predicate says, *`position([Head1 | Tail1], Var1)` is true **if** `Head1` and `Var1` are the same, and if `Tail1` and `Var1` are then succeed*.

Comment: the other example ,, it will start from index 0 and then index 3 , index  0

Comment: so it's return to the same value ,, then it will give false ,,,,, can u give me a solution with explain it mm because i try and can't ,,

Comment: I will lose 10 grades tomorrow if i don't solve it :( ,, plz help me

Comment: Your description says the predicate should *returns true if I start with the same location that I end in*. Shouldn't `find-s([3,2,1,0], 0).` succeed then, since it starts at `0` and goes back to `0`? If not, then your definition for success is missing something.

Comment: no , it's true ,, it succeed

Comment: help pleaaaase ,, any help ?????

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
find_s(L, S) :- nth0(S, L, I), find_s(L, I, S).
find_s(_, S, S).
find_s(L, I, S) :- nth0(I, L, J), find_s(L, J, S).
```

but I think it could easily loop. So, instead of [nth0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth0/3)/3, let's use [nth0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth0/4)/4, after this consideration:

```
?- nth0(2,[a,b,c,d],X,Y).
X = c,
Y = [a, b, d].

?- nth0(2,L,$X,$Y).
L = [a, b, c, d].
```

for sake of readability, let's introduce a replace_nth0/4

```
replace_nth0(P, L, E, LrepE) :-
    nth0(P, L, E, L_Without_E),
    nth0(P, LrepE, -1, L_Without_E).
```

and then

```
find_s(L, S) :- nth0(S, L, I), find_s(L, I, S).
find_s(_, S, S).
find_s(L, I, S) :- I >= 0, replace_nth0(I, L, J, L_rep), find_s(L_rep, J, S).
```

Comment: can you explain it please?

Comment: It's really the simplest translation of your requirements. To understand it, try first to follow the first implementation, using `?- trace, find_s(etc etc).` Then should be clear why it could loop, so - eventually - switch to the second implementation (that one with replace_nth0).

Comment: do your Prolog have nth0?

Comment: should we use recursion ??